# redirect 301 perment to whole site in htacess

Tags: .htaccess

i want to redirect in .htaccess all the site meaning if I go to : **http://oldsite.com/sdsd.php?cal=343**

it will redirect to **http://newsite.com/sdsd.php?cal=343**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RTFM](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```